# Re-use of image FIELDS to insert images in text areas in D7?

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg, media, reusability, imagefield

I am trying to build a site with two main types of content:

- Image Galleries (based on nodes and image FIELDS and Views)
- Some text-based content type like Blog

The workflow will be:

1. Upload and arrange some images in my galleries.
2. Create a blog entry and insert some images in the text.

The catch is that all my images will be managed through **nodes and none will be directly uploaded to the server**. I would like to have some WYSIWYG editor with a button for browsing my galleries (**NOT the server file system**) and use the image size presets (former ImageCache) in Drupal. The best options I have found so far are:

**Image Assist** (http://drupal.org/project/img_assist) would be ideal in this case as it has Views support (in dev) and it can be configured to browse my custom gallery type nodes. The problem is that it is not supported (no stable version with Views support and no intention to port to D7).

**Image Browser** (http://drupal.org/project/imagebrowser) is another good one but it is also not supported and there is D7 version.

I also experimented with **Media and Media Gallery** as they provide an image browser that can potentially fit my needs but found some issues for which I cannot use them:

Media Gallery allows me ot organize my images in galleries but the browser provided by the Media module does not care about galleries: it shows all images in an endless sequence of pages. If I have hundreds of images (and I will) this just doesn't make sense.
To overcome this flaw branch 2.x of Media provides Views support. However Media Gallery does not work with that branch yet and that has been the case for more than an year now ;-(

**My question is: what alternatives exist today to Image Assist amd Image Browser modules for Drupal 7?**

IMCE and the likes don't make much sense to me as they are geared towards browsing the file system and don't necessarily use the D7 image size presets nor they have Views support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [INSERT](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module;it let you inserting photos inside the body field .
[Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) and [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) are great too .
Good luck

Comment: Thank you but the Insert module forces me to attach images to the node where the text is stored. This not not reuse. The whole point of me asking this is that I need to SEPARATE my image galleries from my text content and use already uploaded images instead of uploading them during the text writing.

Comment: Yes..the media module  can help you to do that.. media has few following modules like [media gellery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) or [media nivo slider](http://drupal.org/project/media-nivo-slider)